# Bash Script "useradd" command doesn't execute multiple lines

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash
groupadd -g 1000 ITAS_YR1
groupadd -g 2000 ITAS_YR2
usrY1=1000
usrY2=2000
IFS="," 
while read -r firstName lastName DoB year;
do
    let "usrY1++"
    let "usrY2++"
    if [ "$year" == "Year1" ];
    then
         useradd
        -g ITAS_YR1
        -u $usrY1
        -p "${firstName:0:1}${lastName:0:1}${DoB:6:2}${DoB:0:2}${DoB:3:2}"
        -c "${lastName^}, ${firstName^}"
        --d /home/"${firstName}${lastName}"
        "${firstName:0:1}${lastName}"
        echo Your filesystem has been deleted! Have a great day!                
    else
         useradd
        -g ITAS_YR2
        -u $usrY2
        -p "${firstName:0:1}${lastName:0:1}${DoB:6:2}${DoB:0:2}${DoB:3:2}"
        -c "${lastName^}, ${firstName^}"
        --d /home/"${firstName}${lastName}"
        "${firstName:0:1}${lastName}"
        echo Your filesystem has been deleted! Have a great day!        
    fi
done </home/shaun/Desktop/userdata.csv 
exit 0
```

The issue I'm having with this script is that when it runs, it tries to execute each line in the "then" statement as it's own seperate command, which obviously completely breaks the script.

I've tried moving the "${firstName:0:1}${lastName}" to different parts in the statement, as well as adding \ after each line. Neither of these worked.

Here's a sample of userdata.csv -

```
KARL,APPLEBAUM,09/20/75,Year 1
STEVEN,BARRY,07/18/75,Year 2
DEREK,BENSON,12/12/70,Year 1
FIDEL,CASTRO,04/02/77,Year 1
GEORGE,CHADWICK,01/03/63,Year 1
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe you had trailing whitespace after the '\' characters, so the newlines weren't escaped?  Impossible to say from what you've shown here.   You could always just use a single line for each command, instead of breaking them up.

Comment: This was it! You can't have tab indentation in the middle of a command! Thanks a ton!